# Как реализовать многостраничное приложение с постоянным набором элементов управления

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, ui

Как бы можно было сделать многостраничное приложение, где все страницы были бы с одинаковыми элементами GUI, но значение у них было было собственное?

Я, допустим, хочу создать список счётчиков, все они одинаково выглядят, но сами показатели, естественно, разные.

Просто надо сделать так, чтобы не создавать для каждой страницы по 30 элементов, получая в итоге 100, и с каждым надо прописать все  сигналы/слоты, и для каждого такой создавать отдельно.

Comment: При переключении между страницами меняйте источник данных для элементов gui.

Comment: а это как?)))))

Comment: вопрос непонятен, откуда 30 и 100?

Comment: У меня 3 страницы. На каждом 30 виджетов. 3*30=90, почти 100

Comment: Ну вообще ты создаешь одни класс, который содержит все элементы, сигналы и слоты. А для каждого счетчика ты создаешь объект этого класса.

Comment: Если у вас 30 ел-тов для 90 счетчиков есть вероятность того, что ваша программа будет подглючивать (конечно во многом зависит от машины). Скорее вам нужно продумать более элегантное решение. Например отображение всего одного счетчика и переключатель между данными. А всю работу по сигналам слотам делать в каком нибудь воркере в параллельной среде.

Comment: @Madisson У меня не 90 счётчиков. "3*30=90" 3 счётчиков, 30 эл-нтов, в итоге будет 90 элементов в каждом счётчике по 30 и для каждого надо будет реализовать слот и делать по тысяче строк кода

Comment: @e.n.shirokov а как быть если все элементы находятся в файле.ui?

Comment: @Pon4iPay в любом случае, тебе нужно создать класс-наследник QWidget и натянуть на него ui. Все сигналы и слоты прописываешь внутри. Дальше создаешь сколько хочешь экземпляров этого класса.

Comment: @e.n.shirokov а как их "натянуть-то"?

Comment: @Pon4iPay Это не важно. Главное действительно понять, нужно ли вам видеть 10, 20, 30 счетчиков сразу. Если нет, тогда отрисовать вам нужно один. "а как их "натянуть-то"?" - просто создаешь виджет как обычно(например 5- 6 кнопок).

Comment: https://evileg.com/ru/post/112/
В этой статье показан пример кода такого приложения, а также есть видео, автор которого поясняет, весь код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой широкоиспользуемый шаблон проектирования [Model-View-Controller](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), отталкиваясь от которого, можно решить вашу и другие подобные задачи.

Суть, представленного ниже кода заключается в том, что у нас имеется некая общая модель данных, в которой какому-то однозначному признаку страницы (ключу) ставится в соответствие частная модель данных (данные для конкретной страницы), в качестве которой может выступать что угодно (массив, список, ассоциативный массив, ваш кастомный класс, и так далее).

```
//  Общее количество счетчиков расположенных на QGridLayout (далее грид) 
//  ROW_COUNTxCOL_COUNT
const int ROWS = 6;
const int COLS = 5;

// Имена свойств, необходимых для запоминания позиции счетчика в гриде
const char* ROW = "ROW";
const char* COL = "COL";

// Общая модель данных (В MVC - это Model)
// Здесь
// QString - имя страницы (можно взять Key любого типа, главное, 
// чтобы он однозначно определял данные для страницы)
// QVector<int> данные для счетчиков в пределах [0 до ROWS*COLS -1]
QMap<QString, QVector<int>> pagesData;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->widgetGrid->setDisabled(true);

    QGridLayout* layout = (QGridLayout*)ui->widgetGrid->layout();

    // Создаем все счетчики один раз (В MVC это View)
    for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            QSpinBox* box = new QSpinBox();
            box->setProperty(ROW, row);
            box->setProperty(COL, col);

            layout->addWidget(box, row, col);

            // Сигнал изменения значения в счетчике (это часть Controller'а)
            connect(box, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), this, [=](int value) {
                auto item = ui->listWidget->currentItem();
                if( item ) {
                    QPushButton* button = (QPushButton*)ui->listWidget->itemWidget(item);
                    int row = box->property(ROW).toInt();
                    int col = box->property(COL).toInt();
                    // Сохраняем данные из счетчика в модель данных
                    pagesData[button->text()][col*ROW_COUNT + row] = value;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    layout->setSpacing(0);

    // Сигнал создания новой страницы
    connect(ui->toolButton, &QToolButton::clicked, this, [&]() {

        // Кнопочка в качестве виджета в списке служит для нагладности
        // Можно обойтись без нее
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(QString("Страница %1").arg(ui->listWidget->count() + 1));
        button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem();
        item->setSizeHint(QSize(0, 32));
        ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
        button->setProperty(ROW, ui->listWidget->count() -1);
        ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item, button);

        // Создание новой записи в модели данных
        pagesData.insert(button->text(), QVector<int>(ROWS * COLS, ui->listWidget->count()));

        // Сигнал выбора страницы (это часть Controller'а)
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [button, this]() {
            ui->label->setText(button->text());
            ui->widgetGrid->setEnabled(true);
            QGridLayout* layout = ui->gridLayout;
            ui->listWidget->setCurrentRow(button->property(ROW).toInt());

            // Инициализация данных значениями из модели данных
            for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                    QSpinBox* box = (QSpinBox*) layout->itemAtPosition(row, col)->widget();
                    box->setValue( pagesData[button->text()][col*ROWS + row] );
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваш счётчик рисуется программно, это вообще не проблема - создаёте класс, отнаследованный от QWidget, потом создаёте на главном окне 30 пустых виджетов, а потом в каждом подменяете тип на Ваш (Promote to). Если Вам нужно разместить на нём стандартные элементы управления, то вот [инструкция](http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/customwidget/). Дизайнер для таких элементов у них, похоже, не предусмотрен. Буду рад узнать, если я неправ.